# string clustering: similarity criterion

Tags: clustering, distance

I have a set of strings of dimension $10,000$. I want to group similar strings together in one group, perform clustering. As string metric, I am using the `Levenshtein distance`.

---

Simply, with the `Levenshtein distance` I'll just compute distance between $2$ strings and then by using a threshold the clustering algorithm will make the decision if they can be grouped or not. This is not enough. I am looking for a special measure to study the relation between the strings.

---

**For example:**  **door** and **entrance** wont be grouped together if I just compute the `Levenshtein distance`, in fact there is nothing in common between these $2$ words. But logically they are connected and can be grouped together, since **door** and **entrance** are basically the same.

---

- Have you ever come across such a problem?
- Is it similar to the **Semantic similarity** measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at WordNet. Quoting from http://wordnet.princeton.edu/:

> WordNet is a large lexical database of English. Nouns, verbs,
>   adjectives and adverbs are grouped into sets of cognitive synonyms
>   (synsets), each expressing a distinct concept. Synsets are interlinked
>   by means of conceptual-semantic and lexical relations. The resulting
>   network of meaningfully related words and concepts can be navigated
>   with the browser. WordNet is also freely and publicly available for
>   download.

Comment: yes I was just looking @micans. I found the wordnet website too https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/

I wanted to make sure that I am going in the right direction. What I am looking for is semantic similarity right?

Comment: Semantic similarity does not seem to be a very well defined technical concept, more a loose general term, so I would not worry about 'doing it correctly'. The most important thing is what you want to get from your data. Certainly, WordNet is a highly useful resource and will help you with *meaning* of words. It is a good place to start. Regarding 'Semantic similarity' (e.g. the wikipedia page), I would just use it to gain some background knowledge and/or ideas for future reference. The crucial aspect to all this is your data and what you hope to get from it though.